# streamlet cloud app is not working and the issue is only with cloud working good on local machine

Tags: github, web, cloud, streamlit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epJET.png)When I am running my code of streamlet web app on local machine everything working fine, but if run it on streamlet cloud it is not displaying the result.

I tried by changing the requirements file and finally I gave an empty file, all is not working. My interface is working or displaying, but no results are displayed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DILtr.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.